# Programmatically Check Dynamic File Name For Invalid Characters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I have a SQL Script that runs every night and will generate files showing each Sales Reps production for the previous day.  This works 99% of the time, the 1% it does not work is when one of the variables has invalid characters, which of course would generate an invalid file name.  Is there a t-sql way of checking if @filename is a valid string and if it is not replace @filename with a generic naming convention so the procedure does not error?

Sample syntax below:

```
`Declare @RepName NVARCHAR(500), @filename nvarchar(4000), @Detailedinfo varchar(50)

DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR

  Select Distint repname, saleinfo from dailysalesjournal;

  OPEN cursor1

  FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @RepName, @Detailedinfo

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN

    Set @filename = 'C:\Test\GeneratedFromSQLProc\'+@RepName+'\SaleInfo'+@Detailedinfo+'.csv'

    Print @filename

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @RepName, @Detailedinfo

END

CLOSE cursor1

DEALLOCATE cursor1  `
```

Comment: I don't think there is a "check for a valid filename" function or anything, you'll probably have to do an explicit `REPLACE` for invalid characters you know might be there, based on what you know about the source. I think the invalid windows characters are \ / : * ? " < > and |

Comment: @BradC - I have seen `\ / " * ? <> ` in the filename.  You recommend to do a check once I have set the filename, and if it contains any of those characters to just do a replace?

Comment: Yeah, just run it through a series of `SET @filename = REPLACE(@filename, '\','')` to get rid of any invalid characters.

Comment: No problem, I posted as an answer for posterity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run it through a series of `REPLACE` statements to get rid of any invalid characters:

```
SET @filename = REPLACE(@filename, '\','');
SET @filename = REPLACE(@filename, '/','');
SET @filename = REPLACE(@filename, ':','');
SET @filename = REPLACE(@filename, '"','');
SET @filename = REPLACE(@filename, '*','');
SET @filename = REPLACE(@filename, '?','');
SET @filename = REPLACE(@filename, '<','');
SET @filename = REPLACE(@filename, '>','');
SET @filename = REPLACE(@filename, '|','');
```

If it doesn't contain the character, it'll leave it unchanged. If it finds it, it'll remove it.

Comment: Would the * be considered a wildcard and replace the entire string?

Comment: @SmithStanley No, * and ? aren't SQL wildcards. SQL wildcards are % and _, and those only work in a `LIKE` statement.

Comment: You should add '.' (period) to the list of invalid characters -- the danger is if the filename ends in a period with no extension.  I was using sp_OACreate and sp_OAMethod and didn't pay attention to the filenames -- now I have files and folders I cannot delete because Windows cannot find the file.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to BradC's answer, here's another way to replace troublesome characters using a wildcard:

```
--- These characters are allowed:
DECLARE @allowed varchar(1000)='a-zA-Z0-9 ';

--- Loop through each disallowed character in @filename:
WHILE (@filename COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN LIKE '%[^'+@allowed+']%')
    SET @filename=STUFF(@filename,
                        PATINDEX('%[^'+@allowed+']%',
                                 @filename COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN), 1, '');
```

You can set a SQL Server-style wildcard in the `@allowed` variable to determine which characters are "legal". In my example, I'm allowing lower-case and upper-case A-Z as well as numeric values and space.

Comment: Very interesting approach.  I never thought of setting a variable equal to A-Z and 0-9 then checking the value against that.  I have not tested (yet) but I assume will be much quicker than multiple Replace statements.

Comment: Actually, it's just a loop, so performance for the multiple `REPLACE` statements depends on the number of replacements, whereas the performance of this loop pattern depends on the number of iterations, i.e. the number of characters that need to be replaced. For a single variable like this, execution time will be negligible either way.